browsers cause ubuntu to freeze
I have two computers.  One is an Asus Zenbook running ubuntu 22 with vivaldi.  The other is a dell latitude running ubuntu 24 with firefox.
SO, you'd think they are pretty different environments.  However, both of them regularly crash the OS while running the browser.  Nothing in syslog or journal or anything.  Just a complete freeze.  I can't get in via ssh, the laptops require a hard reboot.
The only common feature here is ubuntu, with a stock install in both cases.  It seems incorrect that the browser should be able to freeze the OS so reliably in such different cases.
